# Can't import json

Tags: python, python-import

I am trying to import json module in python.

I thought I should reinstall json but typing `pip uninstall json` gives me an error saying that it's not installed.

Trying to install it with pip I get a message saying that it is not found. Perhaps trying to install or uninstall this module with pip is foolish for reasons I am too new to understand. I would appreciate an explanation about that also. This is the error message I get if I try `import json`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json_exp.py", line 1, in <module>
    import json
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 106, in <module>
    from .decoder import JSONDecoder, JSONDecodeError
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 3, in <module>
    import re
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\re.py", line 125, in <module>
    import functools
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\functools.py", line 17, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
ImportError: cannot import name 'namedtuple' from 'collections' (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Programs and stuff\Python\collections.py)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide your code as well.

Comment: In your script `collections.py` it is trying to import a bunch of things. you better provide some code, we do not have crystal balls here yet!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the error message: you seem to have a local `collections.py` file (the path reported by ImportError is completely different than that reported for stdlib modules) which shadows the one from the stdlib.

As a result, when `functools` tries to import `namedtuple` it gets your file (which doen't have a namedtuple let alone the one from the stdlib) which blows up.

Comment: That worked! A quick question, does pip not do anything for inbuilt modules?  Also, what info as a noob could I have added in the question to not be downvoted and marked offtopic?

Comment: pip is completely involved in the maintenance and management of the builtin / standard library modules. As for the downvotes and offtopic closures I have no damn idea.